# How can I make a method do something a certain amount of times based on a parameter that is passed in?

Tags: java

```
public void printStars(int level) {

    for (int one = level; one >= 1; one--) {

        for (int two = one; two <= level; two++) {


            System.out.print("*");

        }
        System.out.println();


    }
}
```

I am trying to make something that looks like this:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Currently I am getting about half of the correct diagram all left aligned.

I tried to incorporate printf, but I realized that it wouldn't work because the value of `level` cannot be transferred to the printf method. I was also wondering if there was a way to set the longest segment (the bottom) equal to (2 * level) - 1 stars long and apply some sort of formatting on that to get the answer?

Comment: Is `pyramid` what the above image looks like?

Comment: Use another cycle to print spaces?

Comment: Is it possible to return to a line that is already printed and add more to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print appropriate number of spaces ahead

```
public void printStars(int level) {

    for (int one = level; one >= 1; one--) {
        for(int k=1, k<one;k++){  // print appropriate number of spaces before
            System.out.print(" "); 
        }    
        for (int two = 1; two <=2*(level-one)+1; two++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. if there are N levels in total, and last line doens't have any space. => N-1 levels will have spaces with N-1 in first line, N-2 in 2nd line, so on.. 1 in (N-1)th line.
2. Number of stars: (level-one) gives the line you are printing minus 1, because, initially when one = level (one-level = 0), its 1st line,  next its (level-one) = 1, because one is decreased. & in each line you have to print, 2*X +1 *'s,

Comment: it works, but personally, i feel that i don't learn anything this way. let me try to analyze your code. if i don't understand, i will ask you, ok?

Comment: I have added the explanation to crosscheck with your analysis.

Comment: that matches my thought process

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
public static void printStars(int level) {
    for (int one = 0; one < level; one++) {
      for(int space = 1; space < (level-one); space++){ //<- print leading space
       System.out.print(" ");
      }

      //<- print stars in odd numbers e.g. 1,3,5,7
      for (int two = 0; two < 2*one+1; two++) { 
       System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
 }
```

Comment: @dyoverdx: Is that the out put you got without new lines? Please try the update sample code.

Comment: that is the output without the System.out.println(); method

Comment: there is one extra space before each row of stars, but it is generally correct

Comment: In first `for` loop, please initialize the space as one i.e. `for(int space = 1; space < (level-one); space++){ `. If you think, its helpful, please don't forget to accept the answer.